# Proof using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus

Let the function $f$ be continuous on [a,b] and derivable on ]a,b[

Show that there exists a number $c$ in ]a,b[ such that
$$2c[f(a)-f(b)]=f'(c)(a^2-b^2)$$

From Mean Value theorem ,I know that 
$$f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

But I can't figure out how to prove this

Comment: Cauchy Mean Value Theorem is the key here. Use $g(x) =x^{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\varphi(x)=x^{2}(f(a)-f(b))-f(x)(a^{2}-b^{2})$, one can show that $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)$, so Rolle's Theorem applies here.